# Inside or Interior, which is better to describe a hollow space inside something.

Tags: pronouns

> The inside/interior of that box is partitioned into three spaces.

I think native English speakers may say that "the inside/interior" is unnecessary, but I want to emphasize that the inside/interior is partitioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, there is no difference. There are situations when only one or other is possible:

Inside can be a preposition, interior cannot. So we can say "inside the box" but not *"interior the box".

We use interior when talking about homes, hence "interior design" not "inside design"

However, in your example, there is no significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

It is a mystery how the *outside* of the box could be partitioned. I would rephrase the sentence as

> The box contains three compartments.

This doesn't so much *emphasise* but ***makes clear*** that they are inside the box.